# General Properties\Legal Domain warning on flash

Tags: web-hosting, domains, legal, flash

I had a website containing 2 flash items (menu and banner). Everthing were fine, but for some reasons I had to change its hosting to a new server. Now, I have a warning frame on the banner that says:

> Warning!!! Read this!!!
>
> Please, put this address into the General Properties\Legal Domain: ...

What is this warning for and how can I remove it?

*(The domain did not change)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the banner created using a Flash Menu Labs program? If so, refer to the "Legal Domain" section of the Help files.

> Q. I tried www.domain.com, http://www.domain.com, and domain.com but I
>   still see a warning message over my menu everytime! What can I do?
>   Take a look at the Warning message. It contains a prompt about the
>   proper legal domain. Please read more in "Legal domain" Help section.

http://flashmenulabs.com/faq.htm

Comment: The problem solved. It was a setting in Flash Menu Labs as you said

Answer (score 0):

The program that was used to create the flash items needs an updated license key with new domain name and possible the IP address which is causing it to give you this error.

Comment: Domain did not changes Cold T. Can you tell me how can I remove this warning ?